# How to create and process a 4D sparse matrix in Python efficiently

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a 4D sparse matrix of shape (21x21x21x21). Only one of the element will be set to 1. After which, I will vectorize this matrix and determine the non-zero row. The whole process takes about 6 mins to compute which is too long. Is there a way to do this efficiently in Python?

```
sparseMatrix = np.zeros((21,21,21,21), dtype = np.int8)
#w,x,y,z can be any random integer from 0 to 20.
w = 3
x = 5
y = 18
z = 16
sparseMatrix[w, x, y, z] = 1
sparseMatrix_vec = np.reshape(sparseMatrix, [-1,1])
sparseMatrix_vec_index = np.nonzero(sparseMatrix_vec)[0][0]
```

Comment: In your project, are you sure you're always going to end up with a 21x21x21x21 sparse matrix containing a single 1 ? If this is the case, I think you should simply change your data representation. Simply encode the 1's position using the process that acquires your data.

Comment: @ma3oun, thanks for the reply. Can you give an example of how you would encode this? Yes, I will always end up with a 21x21x21x21 sparse matrix.

Comment: You can also use tensorflow to represent sparse data. Tensorflow supports sparse tensors and these are handled more efficiently. More info here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor

Comment: How is your sparse matrix generated in the first place? I need to know this before I can suggest a way to encode it.

Comment: @ma3oun, Given 21x21x21x21 possible combinations, I just need an unique number for each combination. And it should be a continuous interval, if not a way to map it to continuous interval.

Comment: Instead of storing the index, which can be large, just store (w,x,y,z) if you already know them (referring back to the example you gave)

Comment: @ma3oun, I need (w,x,y,z) to form an unique integer, so that each possible combination can be uniquely identify by an unique integer.

Comment: What's the entire process that takes 6 minutes.  The code you show evaluates without any visible delay.

Comment: `np.ravel_multi_index([w,x,y,z],[21,21,21,21])` gives the same index without constructing the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need (w,x,y,z) to form a unique integer, where each of (w,x,y,z) can vary between 0 and 20, then simply use base 21 representation. The integer you are looking for is:

N = w*(21 ** 0) + x*(21 ** 1) + y*(21 ** 2) + z*(21 ** 3).

Given an integer, you can go back to (w,x,y,z) by using integer division and modulus.